# Importing Solr Cores from one old Solr to another solr(solr version 4 to solr version ) Using Java

Tags: java

I need to change my old solr cores into new solr core using Java Program.
If there Any possible to change the old version solr core into new version solr core?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any implementation. I need the whole solution for that problem.